# Storing multiple values from single function in python

Tags: python, recursion, return

This function prints multiple values, which are indices of a string z, however i want to store those values, and using return will terminate the function leaving me with only the first value of several.

```
def find(a):
    index=a
    while index<len(z)-1:
        if z[index]=="T":
            for index in range (index+20,index+30):
                if z[index]=="A" and z[index+1]=="G" and z[index+2]=="T":
                    a=index
                    print a
        index=index+1
```

Comment: Perhaps use `yield` instead of `print`

Comment: @user2842500: something you might want to read: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to return a `tuple` or `list`:

```
def find(a):
    index=a
    ret = []
    while index<len(z)-1:
        if z[index]=="T":
            for index in range (index+20,index+30):
                if z[index]=="A" and z[index+1]=="G" and z[index+2]=="T":
                    a=index
                    ret.append(a)
        index=index+1
    return ret
```

You can also use [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/373151). I am removing the code for it (you can read the link, it is excellent) because I think returning a `list`makes more sense in your case than `yield`. `yield` makes more sense if you don't intend to always use all of the values returned or if the return values are too many to hold in memory.